# Play template @ symbol behaviour with Option[String]

Tags: playframework-2.0

If in a play template I have an Option[String] passed to the template :

```
@(doc: Option[String])
```

then am I correct in thinking that if the template has this:

```
<p>@doc</p>
```

it will automagically extract the String if it is Some(s) and display but do nothing if it is None?

I guess the implementation of this must be hidden. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `Option[String] => String` operation is done by `play.templates.BaseScalaTemplate._display_` which the template compiler will wrap around your doc reference when it makes a Scala file for your template.

You can find the Scala created for a template under `target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/views/*.scala` if you want to take a closer look at them.